# How can I compute the next Xth day (of the month)?

Tags: php

I want to compute the next Xth day in the calendar.

For example today is 2012-10-08. if X=25 i want it to return 2012-10-25 but if X=06 i want 2012-11-06. If the month doesn't have the required X days, it must return the last day of the month (if i'm looking for the 30th of february for example, it must return 28 or 29 if leap year)

It seems simple enough but I get caught by all the special cases (last month of the year, 28-31 day months, etc).

Comment: Why did the month change when `X=06`

Comment: split the task into individual tasks and search StackOverflow for how to get that date. Next X has been answered before. The rest is using `if`s.

Comment: @Baba Because I want it to find the next X day starting today. This month is already past the 6th so it should return next month's 6th.

Comment: @Bogdan you do know how to use an `if`, do you? Put some more effort into it please and show us what you tried so far. Right now it sounds like you want us to give teh codez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strtotime()` and `t`:

```
$x = 5;                   // given day
if(date('t') < $x){       // check if last day of the month is lower then given day
    $x = date('t');       // if yes, modify $x to last day of the month
}

$month = date('m');       // current month
if(date('d') >= $x){      // if $x day is now or has passed
    $month = $month+1;    // increase month by 1
}

$year = date('Y');        // current year
if($month > 12){          // if $month is greater than 12 as a result from previous if
    $year = date('Y')+1;  // increase year
    $month = 1;           // set month to January
}

if(date('t', strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-01')) < $x){       // check if last day of the new month is lower then given day
    $x = date('t', strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-01'));       // if yes, modify $x to last day of the new month
}

$date = date('d F Y', strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$x));
// 05 November 2012
```

[HERE](http://www.php.net/date) is a nice tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for and not as complicated as I thouhgt. One thing tho: shouldn't the month be computed first and then used to compute the day?

Comment: first you compute day to check last day, then you compute day again to see if it's today or has passed, then you compute month

Comment: Yes but if the month changes the last day also changes.

Comment: I will, I'll also add it to the question tomorow. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again. I feel silly not being able to come up with it on my own...